# How do I uncompress data in PHP which was originally compressed using zlib?

Tags: php, iphone, zlib

I am quite new to Iphone development , so please bear me if I ask some some common questions. In my application I have to transfer data from my Iphone app to a PHP server and for this I have to compress the NSdata in my Iphone app and then pass it on to the PHP server and then Uncompress it in PHP and process the data sent by Iphone in PHP.

For compressing the data in Iphone I have used zlib library.Now on PHP side I want to uncompress this data , but I am unable to do so.

Can anyone help me in uncompressing this data in PHP.

Thanks in Advance.

Gaurav Arora

Comment: [http://php.net/zlib](http://php.net/zlib)

Answer (score 1):

Use `gzuncompress` function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzuncompress.php

Example:

```
<?php
$compressed   = gzcompress('Compress me', 9);
$uncompressed = gzuncompress($compressed);
echo $uncompressed;
```